# ES6 javascript class inheritance, why we need call to super() from derived class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

In javascript ES6, in inheritance,
if derived class has constructor, why it is mandatory to call super from derived constructor ?

few failed examples are -:

. Base with constructor but derived not calling super-

```
 class Base{constructor(){}}
    class Derived{constructor(){}}
    var d = new Derived(); // fails - ReferenceError: this is not defined
```

Comment: try any ES6 compliant  browser ..

Answer (score 6):

> ...it seems it is mandatory to have constructor function in base class.

Not really. If you don't provide one, [one will be provided for you by the JavaScript engine](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation). So there will always be one (it's mandatory in that sense), but it doesn't have to be coded explicitly.

When you don't define a constructor at all, the default one provided by the JavaScript engine for a base class will look like this:

```
constructor( ) { }
```

...and the default one in a derived class will look like this:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

The reason your example fails is that `Derived` has an explicit `constructor`, but that `constructor` doesn't call `super`. You **must** call `super` from within `Derived`'s constructor if you explicitly define one.

> if derived class has constructor, why it is mandatory to call super from derived constructor ?

Because you are required to give the superclass an opportunity to do any initialization of the new object that it has to do. Otherwise, the superclass can't guarantee that it will work correctly, as it may rely on the initialization done by its constructor.

So either:

1. Remove your `constructor` from `Derived`, making it like your first example so that the JavaScript engine will provide the default constructor, or
2. Call `super` from `Derived`'s constructor.

In a comment you asked:

> but if base class does not have any constructor it still fails, if a derived class has

The base class **always** has a constructor, because if you don't provide one (you did in the code in your question), a default is provided. So you still have to call it. While it *could* have been specified as optional if none of the superclasses had a non-default constructor, that would be adding complexity and making `Derived`'s explicit constructor misleading (no call to `super`).

There are also some mechanical reasons: `this` isn't defined until you call `super`, but you're allowed to do things prior to calling `super`, so making the call is necessary to handle the mechanics of `this` in the spec.

Comment: but if base class does not have any constructor it still fails, if a derived class has ..

Comment: @user3359453: Classes always have a constructor, even if you don't provide one. Your `Base` has a constructor (in fact, if it didn't, `Base` wouldn't have a value, because `Base` **is** the constructor). So it naturally follows that a subclass must always call the superclass constructor, because there always is a superclass constructor. Now, it *could* have been specified differently, but it's complexity that doesn't offer any value, so I'm not surprised to see they didn't do it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, good day Mr.Crowder I am great fan of your works, it's been a long time since you gave your perfect answer to this question and I would like to ask one question on the use super() in derived class. That is, why do we need to use super() in the constructor of derived class? Is true that super() is needed to let us use "this" in derived class or...? Please I really need your help. Just why do we need to use super() in derived class.

Comment: @Dickens - `this` is inaccessible in a subclass constructor until after `super` has been called, trying to use it is a `ReferenceError` (https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/05kep9ho/). This is because the object isn't created until just before the base class constructor runs (step 5.a [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget)). You must call `super` at some point in a subclass constructor, it's an `ReferenceError` if you don't (https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/pjdt1m8y/). (JavaScript didn't go the Java way of... *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* inserting a default call for you if you left it out.) You can leave out the subclass constructor *entirely* if you like; if you do, the JavaScript engine will create one for you that looks like this: `constructor(...args) { super(...args); }` (step 10 [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation)). HTH.

Answer (score 3):

It is not mandatory, but if you want to assign properties to the sub-class you need to call `super` in the constructor so that the JavaScript interpreter knows which properties belong to the parent class and which ones to the sub-class.

Let's make an example.

In this case there are no properties assigned, only methods, so JavaScript automatically uses a default empty constructor.

```
class Animal {
  move () {
    console.log('moving');
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  bark () {
    console.log('barking');
  }
}
```

If we want to assign properties to the sub-class though, we need to invoke `super`:

```
class Animal {
  move () {
    console.log('moving');
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor (name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
  }
  bark () {
    console.log('barking');
  }
}
```

The reason is that otherwise the JavaScript interpreter has no way of knowing whether the argument passed to the sub-class constructor (`name`) belongs to the parent class or to the sub-class. So it needs the prgrammer to specify it.

Comment: But why can't the javascript engine hide that implementation detail? in C like languages, you can do shit like `this->parent = parent::construct()`. why javascript? why?