# JavaScript: why super() isn't automatically invoked by the JS engine in a subclass constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript ES6, if `super()` must always be invoked in a subclass constructor before accessing `this`, why isn't it automatically invoked by the JS engine?

Le me make an example:

```
class Animal {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor (name, breed) {
    super();
    this.breed = breed;
  }
}
```

Couldn't it simply be?

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor (name, breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
  }
}
```

I mean, I know the second example doesn't work, but why hasn't this feature been built in JS to automate the process? Why do we have to type `super()` each time? Is there a specific language design constraint that would otherwise break things?

Comment: Duplicates came from this google search: [site:stackoverflow.com javascript why must we  call super](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+why+must+we+manually+invoke+super)

Comment: The Google results of that search do not answer the question at hand.

Comment: Strange, I wonder if I posted a link to a different search. Anyway, I found the duplicates using Google.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might explain it, couldn't find it before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381489/es6-javascript-class-inheritance-why-we-need-call-to-super-from-derived-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the base constructor might contain parameters, in which case you'd have to call `super()` passing them the way you like.

And beyond that, just thinking of pure OOP, there might be various base constructors available with different signatures that would fall under your  control. Automating this process would be unpractical.